# How does ListLinePlot's application of ColorFunction work?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, visualization

(I'm using V12.1)

There are a lot of questions on how to use `ColorFunction` in many plotting functions, but I have not seen this problem mentioned in any of them, nor do the methods I have found seem to solve this issue.

It seems that there's an issue occurring with how exactly `ListLinePlot` is working with the data that is being plotted.

I'd like to note that using such forms as `ylist` below, one can find success in actually coloring the plot according to values in a second list, however, if you use such forms as `xylist`, there seem to be some serious issues that cause the `ColorFunction` to cease working as it should.

```
xylist = {{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}};
ylist = {{2, 4, 8}, {1, 2, 3}};
zlist = {{6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}};
ListLinePlot[ylist, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[{x, y}]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[ylist, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[{y}]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[xylist, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[{x, y}]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[xylist, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[{y}]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[xylist, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, Print[zlist[[##]] &@Position[xylist, {x, y}]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[xylist, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[Position[xylist, {x, y}]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
ListLinePlot[ylist, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Print[Position[ylist, {y}]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
```

Gives this:

```
{1.,2.}

{2.,4.}

{3.,8.}

{1.,1.}

{2.,2.}

{3.,3.}

{1.,2.}

{2.,4.}

{3.,8.}

{1.,1.}

{2.,2.}

{3.,3.}

{2.}

{4.}

{8.}

{1.}

{2.}

{3.}

{2.}

{4.}

{8.}

{1.}

{2.}

{3.}

{1.,2.}

{2.,4.}

{3.,8.}

{1.,1.}

{2.,2.}

{3.,3.}

{1.,2.}

{2.,4.}

{3.,8.}

{1.,1.}

{2.,2.}

{3.,3.}

{2.}

{4.}

{8.}

{1.}

{2.}

{3.}

{2.}

{4.}

{8.}

{1.}

{2.}

{3.}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}

{}
```

## Can anyone tell me what's going wrong with `ListLinePlot`'s use of `ColorFunction` here?

### Why is it parsing through the values twice?

#### Why is it producing empty sets instead of what one would see below--because things like this still work as they should:

```
zlistfunc = 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   Print[zlist[[##]] & @@ Position[xylist, {x, y}][[1]]]];
zlistfunc[2, 4]
(* 5 *)
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what problem you see, though, rather than having us figure it our from running your code?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what the problem is, but I'll put my output, though, it is a bit large, and I figured it wasn't necessary. Updated @MarcoB

The results don't make sense even from a debugging side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the values are passed to `ColorFunction` twice, but I guess that this would only be a problem if the evaluation of the `ColorFunction` were extremely resource intensive.

The fact that `Position` does not return matches as written is probably due to the fact that the values passed to `ColorFunction` are machine-precision, whereas they are exact arbitrary-precision integers in the `xylist` against which you are matching. The two are different to MMA, so `Position` does not find an exact match.

Try either numericizing the list (i.e. `... Position[N@ xylist, {x, y}]...`) or rationalizing the values obtained by the color function (i.e. `... Position[xylist, Rationalize@ {x, y}] ...`).

Comment: Well, seems that was what solved the problem here with this MWE but not for my actual use case. This is really frustrating. I don't understand why `ListLinePlot` using indices is functional for my case, but not for an x-y scheme...

Comment: I use this to color a list of 50,000+ points, it's just pulling the point value from a second list and running a `ColorFunction` on it, so it seems like maybe I am running into issues because the list is so large?

Comment: would it be better to just use a list of x-y-z, and somehow get `ListLinePlot` to only use the x-y, then use `Position` to grab the z value, within the `ColorFunction`?

Comment: Yeah, something's going way wrong with `ListLinePlot`...

Comment: @CATrevillian two things: 1) are you sure that you need to plot 50,000 points? I doubt that the plot will be displayed on a medium with that kind of resolution anyway. 2) given your goal, it may be easier to construct the plots by hand, using styled `Point` or `Line` objects inside `Graphics`.

Comment: well, it’s more like 50 sets of 10 thousand, and then 10 sets of those haha. I am really only in need of plotting that fine to catch a single x-intercept anyways. I suppose I’ll have to go the `Point` route. I will say that the most valuable part of your answer is that the values are passed as machine-precision to `ColorFunction`! Thank you for that, it will help a lot :) I bet that having to parse the list twice for each point is what is making my previous method unfeasible. I wish I knew more why it is doing that, but I have a solution to try! I appreciate your help.